# Java libraries for reading meta data from .img, .osc and .mccd files

Tags: java, binary-data

I need to read meta data from .img, .osc and .mccd files.

Can you anyone recommend any libraries or provide any pointers as to how I would go about doing this. Eventually I need to put that meta-data into an XML file so it can be harvested by a repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find documentation on the file header for these formats and simply read these bytes in. AFAIK no libraries exist sorry.